# how to Load Feature on category page before category name in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

how to Load Feature on category page before category name in Magento 2? In the category page, I share screenshot  link
[enter link description here](https://prnt.sc/n94jmc)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add a description before category name?

Comment: no just I have Load Feature product  on category page before category name only

Comment: Please be precise, the question is not able to understand? @sannikalariya

Comment: Did you have created custom module right?

Comment: yes custom module

Comment: hello friends I show feature product on product page .firstly this feature product show only on category page before category name ... I share image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout catalog_category_view.XML files in your module.

Like app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>  
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_Module::product/customFileName.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: this is right but I am show feature product in category page

Comment: @sannikalariya yes it is possible you have to set block and template from your custom template